Creating MariaDB database on network drive
I'm working with confidential data stored on a network drive, and I need to ensure that this data never leaves the network drive. The data is a 300GB .mysql file that I need to import into a MariaDB database. My setup involves a remote machine where I have mounted this network drive with uid, gid set to ubuntu.
My goal is to create the MariaDB database directly on the network drive due to the confidentiality requirements. I tried to change the datadir in the 50-server.cnf configuration file to a new directory located on the network drive.
However, when I restart the MariaDB service, I encounter the following errors related to InnoDB:
Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The data file './ibdata1' must be writable

Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The data file './ibdata1' must be writable

Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/plugin'

Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

Aug 13 06:11:15  mariadbd[1427288]: 2024-08-13  6:11:15 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Aug 13 06:11:15  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Aug 13 06:11:15  systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I'm not very experienced with MariaDB or setting up databases on network drives, and I'm unsure how to resolve these errors.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The user that owns the MariaDB process must have read/write access to the data directory; apparently that's not the case in your setup.

This looks like the main clue:  The data file './ibdata1' must be writable  -- Check the file system.

What format is the .mysql file? Is this a dump from a MySQL database, i.e. the file contains SQL statements? Or is it binary data? Also, beware that there are several caveats with using NFS (if that is what you're using) for MariaDB storage.

@mustaccio Thank you for your reply! How would I be able to give the appropriate permissions in this case ?

@dbdemon Thank you for your reply! Yes it's an SQL dump file with table definitions at first and the INSERT INTO statements. Is there any other way to create a DB on network drive out of this? The drive is btw NTFS

You need to install an empty database first, then import the SQL dump.
As the root user, run:
mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --group=mysql --skip-test-db    

This should allow you to successfully start MariaDB.
Then import the SQL file. As it's 300GB it will probably take quite a long time.
If the SQL file includes "CREATE DATABASE" statements, then simply:
mariadb < path_to_file.sql

If the SQL file doesn't include any "CREATE DATABASE" statements, then:
mariadb -e "CREATE DATABASE the_db_name_you_want"
mariadb -D the_db_name_you_want < path_to_file.sql

In both cases I assume you already have your credentials (user=root, password, host and port if it's anything other than 3306) in a ~/.my.cnf file. But it's also possible to specify all or some of this on the command-line, of course.
I don't know anything about running MariaDB on an NTFS drive under Linux, but it's not unheard of, so hopefully it will be fine.

Thank you for your reply @dbdemon, would this not however create the database on the standard data directory instead of creating the database on the network drive? I believe when I do CREATE DATABASE , it will be created under /var/lib/mysql which I do not want.

@SarandeepSingh This should use whichever datadir you have defined in your option files (*.cnf files in the MariaDB server's path). You can also specify the datadir as a parameter to mariadb-install-dir: If so, use --datadir=path. This should override whatever the option files say. But you probably want to set this in your option files anyway.
